# Network logon from an impersonation token

Tags: authentication, winapi, impersonation

In a service impersonating a client (using `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient`), I try to call CreateProcessAsUser.
The executable filename is a UNC path located on a third computer (neither the server, nor the client connected to the pipe).

The call fail with the error code 5 (ACCES DENIED). I tried to use `WNetAddConnection2` to authenticate the client from the client (in the context of the token which will be impersonated) before the server calls `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient` but I still get the same error.

How may I authenticate the account impersonated (given the fact that the server only got the impersonation token) in order to gain access to the executable ?

Answer (score 0):

My Win32 is rather rusty so this may be a shot in the dark, but have you tried using the `CreateProcessAsUser` function instead of `CreateProcess`?  According to the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429(VS.85).aspx) it will operate on a restricted token.  If I recall correctly, an impersonation token should suffice.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I made a mistake in my question, of course I use CreateProcessAsUser. The point is that the token is get from ImpersonateNamedPipeClient cannot access the network. (I edited my question)

Comment: The user being impersonated needs network access, as well as needs to have permissions on the third machine.  Are both of those true in your case?

Answer (score 0):

CreateProcessAsUser() needs a primary token, not an impersonated token.  You can use DuplicateTokenEx() to get a primary token from an impersonated token.  The documentation for CreateProcessAsUser() even says as much.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already use DuplicateTokenEx. I've just changed the impersonation level from SecurityImpersonation to SecurityDelegation but I still get the same error if the executable is remote.